# C# code cannot be built properly with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, pdb-files, grasshopper

I want to build a pre_written C# code in VS 2019. The code was built but I only got a .pdb file, not a .gh file(a Grasshopper component). Could you please check the following text and tell me, is there a problem in the building process? How can I solve it?

````
1>------ Build started: Project: Pavillion2015, Configuration: Debug64 Any CPU ------
1>D:\HEXAGONAL\New folder\Pavilion2015_ITECH-master\Pavillion2015\Pavillion\GHC_PointDistributor.cs(207,21,207,57): warning CS0618: 'Curve.Contains(Point3d)' is obsolete: 'Use version that takes a tolerance'
1>D:\HEXAGONAL\New folder\Pavilion2015_ITECH-master\Pavillion2015\Pavillion\GHC_PointsToMesh2.cs(209,29,209,46): warning CS0618: 'Curve.Contains(Point3d)' is obsolete: 'Use version that takes a tolerance'
1>D:\HEXAGONAL\New folder\Pavilion2015_ITECH-master\Pavillion2015\Pavillion\GHC_PointsToMesh.cs(197,29,197,46): warning CS0618: 'Curve.Contains(Point3d)' is obsolete: 'Use version that takes a tolerance'
1>D:\HEXAGONAL\New folder\Pavilion2015_ITECH-master\Pavillion2015\Pavillion\GHC_PointsToMesh.cs(204,25,204,42): warning CS0618: 'Curve.Contains(Point3d)' is obsolete: 'Use version that takes a tolerance'
1>D:\HEXAGONAL\New folder\Pavilion2015_ITECH-master\Pavillion2015\Pavillion\GHC_PointDistributor2.cs(221,21,221,73): warning CS0618: 'Curve.Contains(Point3d, Plane)' is obsolete: 'Use version that takes a tolerance'
1>D:\HEXAGONAL\New folder\Pavilion2015_ITECH-master\Pavillion2015\Pavillion\GHC_MeshRelaxer.cs(47,19,47,28): warning CS0414: The field 'GHC_MeshRelaxer.stopwatch' is assigned but its value is never used
1>D:\HEXAGONAL\New folder\Pavilion2015_ITECH-master\Pavillion2015\Gene-UpdatedCode\GHC_TriLoopDoubleLayer2.cs(33,23,33,36): warning CS0414: The field 'GHC_TriLoopDoubleLayer2.bottomCentres' is assigned but its value is never used
1>D:\HEXAGONAL\New folder\Pavilion2015_ITECH-master\Pavillion2015\Pavillion\GHC_PointDistributor.cs(18,14,18,32): warning CS0414: The field 'GHC_PointDistributor.iAddPointsManually' is assigned but its value is never used
1>D:\HEXAGONAL\New folder\Pavilion2015_ITECH-master\Pavillion2015\Pavillion\GHC_PointDistributor2.cs(18,14,18,32): warning CS0414: The field 'GHC_PointDistributor2.iAddPointsManually' is assigned but its value is never used
1>D:\HEXAGONAL\New folder\Pavilion2015_ITECH-master\Pavillion2015\Gene-UpdatedCode\GHC_TriLoopDoubleLayer2.cs(32,23,32,33): warning CS0414: The field 'GHC_TriLoopDoubleLayer2.topCentres' is assigned but its value is never used
1>  Pavillion2015 -> D:\HEXAGONAL\New folder\Pavilion2015_ITECH-master\Pavillion2015\bin\Pavillion2015.dll
1>  The system cannot find the path specified.
1>          0 file(s) copied.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========```
````

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

double click on "Properties" in the solution explorer and navigate to the "Build Events"

Put in the target file path like shown. This will give you the .gha file in the Build folder

The message you posted shows your build was completed. Probably just didn't set this up.

[image]